General positions in PL topology
Let $I^p$ be the $p$-cube, and write $I^p = I^{p-1} \times I$. Think of $I^{p-1}$ as horizontal and $I$ as vertical, and identify $I^{p-1}$ with $I^{p-1} \times 0$, the base of the cube.
Let $X$ be a polyhedron in $I^p$, a point of $I^p$ is said to lie in the shadow of $X$
if it lies vertically below some point of $X$.
Let $X^*$ be the closure of the set of points of X that lie in the same vertical line as some other point of $X$ (i.e., the set of points of $X$ that either lie in the
shadow of $X$ or else overshadow some other point of $X$). $X^*$ is a sub-polyhedron of X.
My aim is to understand the following proposition.

Let $X$ be a polyhedron in $I^p$ such that $dim = q<p$ and $dim (X \cap \dot{I}^p) \leq q-1$. Then there exists a homomorphism of $I^p$ onto itself throwing $X$ into a position that satisfies the properties:
(i) $X$ does not meet the top or the bottom of the cube
(ii) X meets any vertical line finitely; and
(iii) $dim X^* \leq 2q-p+1$

How can we obtain (iii) using an argument by general positions?
